# I made some changes by my self to the default .htaccess file in codeigniter and now my logout link wont work

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Here is my logout link :

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/login_controller">Schoolam Admin</a>
```

And here is my controller function :

```
public function logout()
    {

        $this->session->sess_destroy();

        $data['logout'] = 'true';
        $this->load->view('login.php', $data);
    }
```

This is my base_url :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/schoolam/admin/';
```

Comment: shouldn't you be including the .htaccess file since that's what you changed?

Comment: `href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/login_controller/logout"`??

Comment: i did include the .htaccess back but did not help

Comment: Sorry gave the wrong link for logout. This is it:

Comment: <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/login_controller/logout"><i
                                class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>

Comment: what is the issue now??

Comment: Actually what happen When you click Logout link ?? Please specify @RohitSidhwani .

Answer (score 1):

Remove **`.php`** in here

```
$this->load->view('login.php', $data);
                         ^^^
```

**So final code is**

```
$this->load->view('login', $data);
```

---

And **logout** link should be (add ***controller method `login_controller/logout`***)

```
<a class="navbar-brand" 
href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/login_controller/logout">Schoolam Admin</a>
```

Comment: ya.. you are correct... i mentioned also in comments.

Comment: Sorry but this did not help. You are right, the correct way to load the view does not include '.php' but it works fine with it aswell. The issue is with the .htaccess. I have deleted the .htaccess i changed and added the previous one but still the same problem

Comment: I created a new directory in my xampp/htdocs and setup codeigniter again and transferred the same files to that directory and that fixed it. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: It solved. It good. But, you should know the reason why it was not working there Mr @RohitSidhwani

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju thanx buddy